# Is "further strengthen" or "further bolster" redundant?

Tags: redundancy, intensifying-adverbs

For example,

> To further strengthen my graduate school application, I studied Spanish in Argentina for a semester.

The wording seems redundant and awkward to me, but it's common and I'd like some SE users' input.

Comment: Is this a sentence that you intend to include in your written application, or did you write it in some other context?

Comment: It may or may not be redundant depending on context. But even if it's redundant, it's not incorrect, merely redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could *strengthen* your application by doing X, but the next step would be to ***further strengthen*** it by doing Y.

Most of the time, *strengthen* would be more than adequate to use in these examples, but if you're providing a list of things to help your application, then the second, third, and fourth things you did may be ***further*** actions.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. It's like saying,

> I want to improve my computer skills. But once you do that, you can say,
>
> I want to further improve my computer skills.